# Multiple application instances on the same database

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, multi-tenant

I'm writing an application that that I'm going to provide as a service and also as a standalone application.
It's written in Zend Framework and uses MySQL.

When providing it as a service I want users to register on my site and have subdomains like customer1.mysite.com, customer2.mysite.com.

I want to have everything in one database, not creating new database for each user.

But now I wonder how to do it better.
I came up with two solutions:
1. Have user id in each table and just add it to WHERE clause on each database request.
2. Recreate tables with unique prefix like 'customer1_tablename', 'customer2_tablename'.

Which approach is better? Pros and cons?
Is there another way to separate users on the same database?

Leonti

Comment: Very interesting question! I'm working on a simlar project and I'm very curious to the opinions here! @Leonti; are you renting a server and providing every user an own hostingenv.? Or are you just storing all files in a dir, based on their customer ID or whatsoever? And how are you thinking about emailaddresses per client?

Comment: The way I'm going to do it is just one application on a hosting and dynamic subdomains with mod_rewrite.
So when user goes to customer1.mysite.com application looks into database for customer1's id and then acts accordingly.
This way when I update an application it updates for all users at the same time.
There is no need for email addresses in my application, so I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would stick to keeping all the tables together, otherwise there's barely any point to using a single database. It also means that you could feasibly allow some sort of cross-site interaction down the track. Just make sure you put indexes on the differentiating field (`customer_number` or whatever), and you should be ok.

If the tables are getting really large and slow, look at [table partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html).

Comment: If you choose MyISAM, note that it has table-level locks. E.g. one client is doing an UPDATE on their rows of the table, all the other clients have to wait until it completes. InnoDB doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I think this is what I'm going to do.
Since my application will be evolving it would be hard to alter all the tables for every customer.

Comment: Piskvor, thank you for the note - didn't know that. It saved me a lot of hair pulling in a future :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you intend to do with the data. If the clients don't share data, segmenting by customer might be better; also, you may get better performance.

On the other hand, having many tables with an identical structure can be a nightmare when you want to alter the structure.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using separate databases for each user. This makes your application easier to code for, and makes MySQL maintenance (migration of single account, account removal and so on.)

The only exception to this rule would be if you need to access data across accounts or share data.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a multi-tenant application and lots of people run them; see

[multi tenant tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-tenant)

For some other peoples' questions